# How to desing the component which take textfile,csv, or any other custom file and load it in AZURE DB tables

Tags: azure, c#-4.0, azure-sql-database, azureservicebus, servicebus

I am looking for the proper kind of architecture to get the data loading done from text files, csv etc... (format is not decided yet) and load it into Azure SQL Database table(s).

It should not be done manually by the user, I want this workflow to happen automatically, provide input for the components, and I need use a service so that it will be a fail safe process.

Please provide approach or architecture which does the similar job.

Answer (score 1):

There are a number of ways to do this an it really depends on your goals and how much you want to invest.

Since you mention CSV by default you could script a SQL bcp (bulk copy).
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms162802.aspx

You could script it so it isn't manual, but you mentioned it should be fail safe.  Any group insert of row into an existing table could fail for a number of reasons (referential integrity checks, hardware issues, locks, etc).

Most integration architectures would bulk copy the data to a clean staging location (empty or new table in the same or other database) using either BCP or SqlBulkCopy (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7ek5da1a(v=vs.110).aspx).  Then they would loop through those rows inserting them to the final destination table.  That way you can build in either retry or report failures on a row by row basis, and handle accordingly.

Since this is in Azure, there are a number of ways to do the final loop through rows process, like Azure Batch, or Azure Jobs, or even Azure Logic Apps (this is basically a BizTalk like workflow/integration support engine), or custom worker role.